My multi threaded rayon Rust loop can't outperform my Signlethreaded loop
I've been creating a function that is supposed to a BigUint into the base 1048576. I've been paralyzed by a problem I'm not quite sure how to solve.
I originally made a single threaded varient but on larger files it would freeze up my program, use 100% of my CPU, and in general take a long time. I assumed the right approach to scaling up would be making a varient that utilized multiple cores but that to has failed but I don't understand why.
My Single threaded varient:
fn deci_convert(number: &mut BigUint, map: &HashMap<u32, char>) -> String {
    println!("Decimal conversion start");
    let base = BigUint::from_u32(1048575).unwrap(); // Create BigUint once for base
    let mut temp_string = String::new();

    // Precompute powers of base up to the needed value
    let mut base_powers = vec![BigUint::one()];
    let mut current_power = BigUint::one();

    while &current_power <= number {
        current_power *= &base;
        base_powers.push(current_power.clone());
    }
    base_powers.pop(); // Remove the last power as it exceeds the number

    while *number != BigUint::zero() {
        for i in (0..base_powers.len()).rev() {
            if &base_powers[i] <= number {
                let digit = (&*number / &base_powers[i]).to_u32().unwrap();
                *number %= &base_powers[i];
                if let Some(&c) = map.get(&digit) {
                    temp_string.push(c);
                } else {
                    panic!("Digit not on the map. The digit that caused the issue is {}", digit);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    temp_string
}

My Multithreaded Varient:
fn _par_deci_convert(number: &mut BigUint, map: &HashMap<u32, char>) -> String {
    println!("Parallel decimal conversion begins");

    let base = 1048575u32;
    let base_biguint = BigUint::from_u32(base).unwrap();
    
    // Compute the maximum exponent
    let max_exponent = (0..)
        .take_while(|&i| *number >= base_biguint.pow(i as u32))
        .last()
        .unwrap_or(0);

    // Precompute base powers
    let base_powers: Vec<BigUint> = (0..=max_exponent)
        .map(|i| base_biguint.pow(i as u32))
        .collect();

    println!("Deci convert started");

    // This mutex will be used to safely modify the string in parallel
    let result = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));

    // Parallel processing of base powers
    base_powers.into_par_iter().rev().for_each(|base_power| {
        let mut local_number = Arc::new(Mutex::new(number.clone()));

        let digit = {
            let mut num = local_number.lock().unwrap();
            let digit = (&*num / &base_power).to_u32().unwrap();
            *num %= base_power;
            digit
        };

        if let Some(&c) = map.get(&digit) {
            let mut result = result.lock().unwrap();
            result.push(c);
        } else {
            panic!("Digit not on the map, you messed up somewhere. Digit: {}", digit);
        }
    });

    // Collect the final result
    let final_result = Arc::try_unwrap(result).unwrap().into_inner().unwrap();

    println!("Deci convert finished");

    final_result
} 


You might have a contention on your mutex. Instead of for_each() and mutex, you might want to use map() and collect() into a vector of digits, and then trivially create a string out of that vector.

Also, you don't need to wrap shared data in Arc when using Rayon.

@user4815162342 I tried removing the Arc but rust-analyzer gave me a lot of errors that I didn't know how to resolve otherwise.


I originally made a single threaded varient but on larger files it would freeze up my program, use 100% of my CPU

It's a CPU bound loop, what else would it do but take 100% of a core until it's done?

I assumed the right approach to scaling up would be making a varient that utilized multiple cores but that to has failed but I don't understand why.

Because you're barely doing any work per iteration but you're adding a ton of overhead with an allocation (which is useless) and two different locks (one of which is useless), as well as a ton of contention on the result mutex which every iteration needs to acquire.
Not only that, but your algorithm seems strictly linear since every iteration in the original modifies number in-place, something the purportedly parallel code does not do, instead each iteration has a copy of the original.
Finally the entire thing seems way over-complicated because you're working in base 10: 1048576 is 2^20, so you can shift / mask groups of 20 bits to get each digit with no dependency whatsoever between them.
Also why would you need a hashmap between u32 and char when char::from_u32 exists?

probably could've used char::for_u32 but I already established the Hashmap, I'll probably make it to where it could be randomized too so it could be used to make secret keys as well. I did a lot of the extra stuff in an attempt to precompute my values so it wouldn't be as slow too. I was inexperienced with rayon because I usually use loops instead of iter so I used chat gpt to help too and I assumed precomputation was the route to go when processing megabytes to gigabytes. Could you give me an example, I know shifting bits is an unsafe operation.
